# how does the begin argument in svg work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a a SVG animation that works fine, but I have a problem when it comes to the begin argument, I want it to fire when entering the view and not when loaded.

Is there any way i can fire this trough javascript? or inline SVG?

```
<animate id="fillAnimation" xlink:href="#p2"
                            begin="100ms"
                            attributeType="XML" 
                            attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
                            fill = "freeze"
                            from="4000"
                            to="0"
                            dur="2000ms"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

Try using **Snap.svg:**

http://snapsvg.io/

This could be helpful for you:

http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.animate